# Set up SSHFS automated mounting only when user SSH into remote server?

Tags: ssh, sshfs

i want to set up SSHFS such that whenever I SSH into remote server, it mounts the file transfer folder. Is it possible to set it up in such way?

---

making script after @Alex's comment.

my script is very simple.

```
#! /bin/bash
#login in the server
ssh -X user@0.0.0.0
#establish the automated mounting
sshfs user@0.0.0.0:/home/usr/data /usr/some/place/mountedfolder/ -ovolname=mounted-folder
```

but now, if i execute this file. first the ssh is established and then only after i exit ssh the folder is mounted with `sshfs`.

What am i doing wrong here?

---

okay for now, i just did simple fix :-> switched the order of commands. first the `sshfs` and then `ssh` so that : first it mounts and second it establishes `ssh` connection.

```
#! /bin/bash
#establish the automated mounting
sshfs user@0.0.0.0:/home/usr/data /usr/some/place/mountedfolder/ -ovolname=mounted-folder
#login in the server
ssh -X user@0.0.0.0
```

seems like it works for now.

Comment: Just run `SSHFS` then `ssh` in the same shell script.

Comment: this could be.. i am right now just using the single line on the terminal to ssh. may be yes make a script to do both. thanks for the idea. i feel dumb now.

Comment: @Alex : i nearly went full retard, just re-read your comment again and you do point out the order of execution for the commands -.-

Comment: No, you good. As old wisdom says: "The only those who doing nothing never makes mistakes"

Comment: I think you have to move the corrected(working) part of the script to the answer and accept your own answer, it absolutely Ok with policy of this site and those who would look for the similar solution may find it useful

Comment: No problem, I would advise you to add one more line of code - run SSHFS unmount command after `ssh`. This way if you logout from remote machine, it will automatically unmount SSHFS too, releasing mount point for something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a simple script following @Alex's advice that first mounts and then `ssh` to the remote server. This works as wanted.

```
#! /bin/bash
#establish the automated mounting
sshfs user@0.0.0.0:/home/usr/data /usr/some/place/mountedfolder/ -ovolname=mounted-folder
#login in the server
ssh -X user@0.0.0.0
#unmounting the directory after logout
umount user@0.0.0.0:/home/usr/data
```

To make it easier to run the script i just made it executable by following the two steps below :

1. I wrote a simple script named `sshautomatic.sh` in `/usr/local/bin` (I use OSX)
2. then in `/usr/local/bin` establish a symlink by  : `sudo ln -s sshautomatic.sh sshautomatic`
3. finally, make `sshautomatic.sh` executable by : `chmod +x sshautomatic.sh`
   Now, you can  establish the fusemounting and ssh connection from terminal by just typing the command `sshautomatic`